# how to clear/drop table and the recreate it and populate in django

Tags: python, django

I need to refresh a table every day so I want to make a python script to drop a table form the database or clear it, recreate it and the repopulate it with a new data from a csv file. 
How can I clear the data from the table or drop the table and then recreate it?

Comment: WHat did you try that didn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can use [sqlclear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlclear-app-label-app-label) like so:

```
python manage.py sqlclear my_app | python manage.py dbshell
```

but then you need to create the table again with `syncdb`.

You could also just delete all posts in your table with `MyApp.objects.all().delete()`

Comment: __Warning__: the first method will clear _all_ tables in the app. If you have multiple models in the same app, this method might not be what you want.